# getting URI from cpanel database

Tags: database, cpanel, prisma

I'm trying to deploy my database on my Cpanel hosting database but I need the `URI` for that.

I'm using Prisma ORM and I want to use the `URI` in my `.env` file.

Comment: Do you mean getting the database connection string from the database?

Comment: yes. now im using mysql. im using this method to connect to my database :
mysql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASE

but I'm getting auth error. idk why. i double checked my information

Comment: Did you tried out this guide: https://www.knownhost.com/kb/how-to-connect-to-mysql-remotely-in-cpanel/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried his method `mysql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASE`
but My host provider was blocking this option ( remote access )
So I changed my host provider and it is fixed now!